# timezone converter in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, timezone, class-library

How do I write a timezone converter library in c#? or is there an existing timezone class I could use?

I will need the timezone database and be able to use it to calculate/convert from one UTC timezone to another timezone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Try [Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/).

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Afk.TimeZone](https://github.com/LZorglub/TimeZone), the package is based on IANA timezone database.